# ggplot2 plot stat_smooth grouped by variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gam

```
> head(d)
  TargetGroup2012 TargetGroup2000     bmi3 age3 PA_Score education3 asthma3 allasthma3 tres3
1               2               2 20.89796   55        2          2       0          0     0
2               2               2 20.20038   49        3          2       0          0     0
3               2               2 30.47797   58        3          1       0          0     0
4               2               2 34.13111   51        2          2       0          0     0
5               3               2 23.24380   52        3          1       0          0     0
6               3               2 16.76574   62        2          3       0          0     0
  wheeze3 SmokingGroup_Kai
1       0                4
2       1                4
3       0                5
4       1                4
5       0                3
6       0                3
```

I am doing a `gam` plot using:

```
MyFormula=asthma3~s(bmi3)+s(age3)+PA_Score+eucation3
c <- ggplot()
c + stat_smooth(data=d,aes(bmi3,asthma3),method="gam",formula=MyFormula,color="red")+
stat_smooth(data=d3,aes(b3,as3),fomula=as3~s(b3))+xlab("BMI3")+ylab("Asthma3")
```

I would like to have different lines on the same plot according to the value of the variable `TargetGroup2012`.

I can obtain this doing:

```
d1=d[d$TargetGroup2012==1,]  
d2=d[d$....]
And then plot...
```

Is there a faster way to do that? Maybe using something like groupby?

EDIT : 
Correct solution

```
d=data[,c("TargetGroup2012","TargetGroup2000","bmi3","age3","PA_Score","education3","asthma3","allasthma3","tres3","wheeze3","SmokingGroup_Kai")]
d$TargetGroup2012=factor(d$TargetGroup2012)

d=na.exclude(d)

ggplot() + stat_smooth(data=d,aes(x=bmi3,y=asthma3,group=TargetGroup2012,color=TargetGroup2012),method="gam",fomula=asthma3~s(bmi3)+s(age3)+PA_Score+SmokingGroup_Kai)+  xlab("BMI3")+ylab("Asthma3")
```

Comment: You can use `group=TargetGroup2012` inside your `stat_smooth` function.

Comment: That is partially working. I would like to obtain lines of different color with a legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get lines with different colors, you can use `color=TargetGroup2012` inside your `stat_smooth` function. That should give you the desired result.